# How to use Ansible modules replace or inline instead shell command with SED

Tags: ansible, sed, ansible-playbook, yaml, search-and-replace

i have file with string:

```
MYAPP.db.username.DEV=MYUSERNAME
```

Where:

```
MYAPP mean name of applications
DEV means environment
MYUSERNAME means name of user for connection to db
```

I need to replace these variables according to variables, that i have in some script.
I am using this:

```
- name: Replace line
  shell: sed -i "/{{ name_of_app }}.db.username.{{ name_of_environment }}/c\\{{ name_of_app }}.db.username.{{ name_of_environment }}={{ name_of_user_to_db }}" /path/to/my/apps/{{ name_of_app }}/config/{{ name_of_app }}.config
```

It works fine, but i see warnings in output of ansible

```
 [WARNING]: Consider using the replace, lineinfile or template module rather
than running sed.  If you need to use command because replace, lineinfile or
template is insufficient you can add warn=False to this command task or set
command_warnings=False in ansible.cfg to get rid of this message.
changed:
```

I have tried this

```
- name: Replace line via replace method
  replace: 
    dest: "/path/to/my/apps/{{ name_of_app }}/config/{{ name_of_app }}.config"
    regexp: "{{ name_of_app }}.db.username.{{ name_of_environment }}"
    replace: "{{ name_of_app }}.db.username.{{ name_of_environment }}={{ name_of_user_to_db }}"
```

and this

```
- name: Replace line via lineinfile method
  lineinfile: 
    dest: "/path/to/my/apps/{{ name_of_app }}/config/{{ name_of_app }}.config"
    regexp: "{{ name_of_app }}.db.username.{{ name_of_environment }}"
    line: "{{ name_of_app }}.db.username.{{ name_of_environment }}={{ name_of_user_to_db }}"
    backrefs: yes
```

each time, i have result with failed:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (replace) module: when Supported parameters include: after, attributes, backup, before, content, delimiter, directory_mode, encoding, follow, force, group, mode, owner, path, regexp, remote_src, replace, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, unsafe_writes, validate"}
```

Can you help me, where i have error in my playbook ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html) and the [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html#parameters) use the `path` parameter to mark

> The file to modify.
>   `lineinfile` module is used to
>
> ensure[s] a particular line is in a file, or [to] replace an existing line using a back-referenced regular expression.

Use

> the replace module if you want to change multiple, similar lines

I believe the `dest` parameter is used for modules creating new files like `template` or `copy`.

Just replace `dest` with `path` and both provided examples should work as expected.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. The official doco indicates `dest` is an alias for `path` in both modules, but I am not surprised it is not working in this case.

Comment: Ansible changed this behaviour with version `2.3` (released 2017) This answer might be out of date by now.